# Updating related tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to update two tables in MySQL with PHP. The second table needs the ID of the row being inserted in the to first table.

At the moment I have some PHP code that loops through this process for each of the items in an array:

1. Check if record exists by attempting to get it's ID.
2. If the record doesn't exist insert it and get the last insert ID.
3. Update the second table using the ID we found as a foreign key.

This is very inefficient as multiple database calls are made. I would rather store the data in two arrays, one for each table, then batch insert them when the loop is done. The problem is I need to get the ID of the row in the first table before I can do this.

This is a problem I come across a lot. What is the most efficient / 'best practice' way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you perform these steps:

1. Batch insert records into table1
2. Batch update of records in table2 (you need criteria to match which record from table1 is in relation with record from table2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create stored procedure for inserting whole hierarchy in one server call. Supply all parent-child records as XML and parse it/insert records inside procedure (afaik MySql should have XML-functions similar to MS SQL). This will result in the same number of INSERT statements however they will execute on server side which should improve performance. E.g.

```
exec MySp @myHierarchy = '<Recs><Parent Name="P1"><Child Name="C1" /><Child Name="C2"/></Parent></Recs>'
```